# How to draw a QPoint on a QGraphicsView/Scene

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

It's really not clear to me how to simply draw a 2d point in QT. I want it to overlay a QPixmap item, but every piece of documentation I find talks about drawing polygons with brushes.

Thanks in advance -

Comment: A point generally is a polygon, are you trying to color only a single pixel? If not just use QGraphicsScene::AddRect or QGraphicsScene::addEllipse

Answer (score 3):

From [Qt's documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qpixmap.html):

> QImage is designed and optimized for
>   I/O, and for direct pixel access and
>   manipulation, while QPixmap is
>   designed and optimized for showing
>   images on screen.

So if you have a QPixmap, convert it to QImage and then use [QImage::setPixel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qimage.html#setPixel):

```
QImage image = pixmap->toImage();
image.setPixel(2, 4, 0x0000ff);
ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image)); // show the image in a label
```